# NSI Script to equivalent to bat script

Tags: batch-file, nsis

I wrote following commands in `.bat` file which works for me quite well. Now I am trying to write a `NSIS` based graphical installer and need to reproduce the same with `NSIS`. I do not understand how I can get this done.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin
set RAILS_ENV=production
cd C:\myapp
bundle install --local
```

I would like to know how to write a `nsi` script which would be equivalent to the above commands being run in shell one after another.

Answer (score 7):

You need to be a little careful when updating %PATH% in NSIS because the NSIS string length limit is shorter than the %PATH% length limit. You can work around this by calling the Windows API directly:

```
!define ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND 203

!if "${NSIS_PTR_SIZE}" <= 4
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function ProcessEnvAppendPath ; IN:Path OUT:N/A
System::Store S
Pop $1
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetEnvironmentVariable(t "PATH", t, i0)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "PATH", tr1)'
${Else}
    StrLen $2 $1
    System::Call '*(&t$0,&t1,&t$2)i.r9'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetEnvironmentVariable(t "PATH", ir9, ir0)i.r0'
    StrCpy $2 0
    ${IfThen} $0 > 0 ${|} IntOp $2 $0 - 1 ${|} 
    System::Call '*$9(&t$2,&t1.r2)' ; Store the last character from %PATH% in $2
    StrCpy $3 ';'
    ${IfThen} $2 == ';' ${|} StrCpy $3 "" ${|}
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrcat(ir9, tr3)' ; Append ";" or ""
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::lstrcat(ir9, tr1)'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "PATH", ir9)'
    System::Free $9
${EndIf}
System::Store L
FunctionEnd
!endif

Section
Push "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin"
Call ProcessEnvAppendPath
System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "RAILS_ENV", t "production")'
SetOutPath "C:\myapp" ; Sets the process working directory
ExecWait '"bundle" install --local' ; You should probably use the full path to bundle here.
SectionEnd
```

Another alternative would be to write the batch file on the fly and execute it with the `nsExec` plugin.

Comment: For now the alternative sounds better to me.